# Confused by Coq imports

Tags: import, module, coq

Can someone please tell me the differences between

- `Require` *Name*.
- `Require Import` *Name*.
- `Import` *Name*

?

Answer (score 9):

- `Require`: load an external library (typically from the standard library or the `user-contribs/` folder);
- `Import`: imports the names in a module. For example, if you have a function `f` in a module `M`, by doing `Import M.`, you will only need to type `f` instead of `M.f`;
- `Require Import`: does both `Require` and `Import`.