# Require, Import, Require Import

Tags: import, module, coq

In Coq, what's the difference between ... ?

- `Require X.`
- `Import X.`
- `Require Import X.`

I have basically memorized some common patterns. I usually see code using `Require Import X`. Then there's `Import ListNotation`. And I just noticed it's also possible to write just `Require X`. What's the difference? Some practical examples would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33854672/2747511).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Require` loads a library whereas `Import` brings its definitions into scope. `Require Import` does both. If you only have the library loaded, you'll need to refer to names fully qualified. Coq allows top-level modules corresponding to files to define modules; these have to be imported separately to bring all of their definitions into scope, and they can't be `Require`d - that's what's going on with `ListNotations`:

```
(* List is not loaded by default *)
Fail Check List.map.

(* the full name is technically Coq.Lists.List *)
Require List.

(* note that lists are actually defined in Coq.Init.Datatypes which is 
imported by default, so [list] is  unqualified and the [x::xs] notation is 
already defined *)
Print List.map.
(*
List.map =
fun (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) =>
fix map (l : list A) : list B :=
  match l with
  | nil => nil
  | (a :: t)%list => (f a :: map t)%list
  end
    : forall A B : Type, (A -> B) -> list A -> list B
*)

(* bring everything in List into scope *)
Import List.
(* this includes the ListNotations submodule *)
Import ListNotations.

(* note that now list notations are available, and the list notation scope is
open (from importing List) *)
Print List.map.
(*
map =
fun (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) =>
fix map (l : list A) : list B :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | a :: t => f a :: map t
  end
    : forall A B : Type, (A -> B) -> list A -> list B
*)
```

Note there are some quirks with how Coq handles modules, especially compared to other languages:

- Coq does not require a full path to a module, only an unambiguous suffix. Indeed I rarely see full import paths, even to standard library modules.
- Notations cannot be used except by importing the module, and unlike most objects there's no way to refer to a notation, fully qualified or otherwise.
- Importing a module can have side effects, for example changing notation interpretation scopes or setting options if you use `Global Set` in the module being imported.
- Importing is fairly limited (especially compared to Haskell) - there's no way to rename a module at import time, or selectively import some definitions.