# Scopes in Coq - importing without resolution?

Tags: coq

Consider the sample code:

```
Require Import BinNat.
Open Scope N.

Check (N.ones).
(* Error: The reference ones
   was not found in the current environment. *)
Check (ones).
```

How do I import `BinNat` in such a way that I don't have to resolve `ones` to `N.ones`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Import` command can help:

```
From Coq Require Import BinNat.
Import N.
About ones.
```

Comment: Ah, So, what *are* the precise semantics of `Import` versus `Require Import`, and what is this called? "name resolution"? "scopes"? I couldn't find this in the Coq manual

Comment: Please take a look at [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47973622/2747511) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33857656/2747511). HTH

Comment: For future reference of anyone who stumbles on this:
Semantics of Import: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html#coq:cmd.import

Semantics of Require: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html?highlight=import#coq:cmd.require